# ASP.NET Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: asp.net

I have problem with that code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Examples/my.aspx");
//or
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Examples/my.aspx",true);
```

the code above generates the error as I mentioned at this topic's title.

I simply need to refresh my ASP.NET page, I can't use that code instead:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Refresh","2");
```

because it says about IIS pipeline mode

The puprose is that I must get into OnLoad method where some conditions are true after refresh/redirect

Answer (score 1):

Try with the Following Code

> strURL = ""~//Examples//my.aspx"";
>
> ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,
>   this.GetType(), "red",
>   "window.location.href='" + strURL +
>   "';", true);

Answer (score 0):

Are you capturing the ThreadAbortException? You can try modifying your code to read:

HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Examples/my.aspx",false);

You might find more helpful information at the following link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/

Answer (score 0):

add false in redirect only 
it works with me

Comment: expand your answer by example, please

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide the specific snippet of code that works for you.